# Running a match query from SQL server to a link SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite

I have not worked with Linked tables in SQL Server as yet, my question is:

I need to run a match query from my database `Jester` table `dbo.Retail` vs my linked Database `FDLINK` database `FD_22AE5D15` table `dbo.FD_Documents`

Columns in `Jester.dbo.Retail`

```
Client_Number
1252632
2545895
1254786
2548563
```

Columns in `FDLink.FD_22AE5D15.dbo.FD_Documents`

```
FD_B61DDE99 - CLIENT_NUMBER, FD_CBAF8917 - DOC_TYPE
```

I would like to run something link this.

```
select Jester.dbo.Retail.CLIENT_NUMBER, 
FDLink.FD_22AE5D15.dbo.FD_Documents.FD_CBAF8917
from Jester.dbo.Retail, FDLink.FD_22AE5D15.dbo.FD_Documents
where Jester.dbo.Retail.CLIENT_NUMBER = FDLink.FD_22AE5D15.dbo.FD_Documents.FD_B61DDE99
```

result should be;

```
Client_Number, FDLink.FD_22AE5D15.dbo.FD_Documents.FD_CBAF8917 -Doc_Type
    1252632  ,   ID
    2545895  ,   OTHER
    1254786  ,   ID
    2548563  ,   POR
```

Secondly I need to find out what clients have all three document types

```
Client Number
1252632 = 2 , ID, OTHER
2545895 = 3 , ID, OTHER, POR
```

Apologies for this long question, but I need to learn somehow.

Comment: First result can be obtained using the query :SELECT r.CLIENT_NUMBER, f.FD_CBAF8917
FROM Jester.dbo.Retail r
 INNER JOIN FDLink.FD_22AE5D15.dbo.FD_Documents f
 ON r.CLIENT_NUMBER = f.FD_B61DDE99

Comment: Second result can be obtained using the query : SELECT r.CLIENT_NUMBER,
(STUFF((SELECT ',' + DocType
            FROM FDLink.FD_22AE5D15.dbo.FD_Documents innerD
            WHERE innerD.FD_B61DDE99 = r.CLIENT_NUMBER
   FOR XML PATH('')   
  ) ,1,1,'')) AS Doc_Type,
f.FD_CBAF8917 
FROM Jester.dbo.Retail r 
INNER JOIN FDLink.FD_22AE5D15.dbo.FD_Documents f 
ON r.CLIENT_NUMBER = f.FD_B61DDE99
GROUP BY r.CLIENT_NUMBER

Comment: HI @Rajesh, thank you for your assistance. however when this script executes, it gives me error, OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for "FDLink" returned message "Query timedout expired". msg 7399, level 16, stat 1, line 1

Comment: Do you have the LinkedServer created and mapped. You need to make sure that your LinkedServer works fine

Comment: yes the link has been created and mapped correctly, as far as I know?

Comment: I Can run a direct query on FDLink

Comment: Can you post the query that you have used to check that the linked server works?